# How to autofix resolution of website on mobiles of different browsers?

Tags: php, html, css, web, screen-resolution

I have created a website for my college.In that there are some resolution issues If I open in a web browser I can view it properly, But when I open it in a mobile phone the total website is not looking good can anyone help me out ? I'm providing the link below :

http://mvsrec.edu.in/ieee/

Comment: You can use css frameworks like bootstrap. They have responsive design layout which will work on your mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

> For compatibility with mobiles and responsiveness of the WebSite.

```
You can use the following
```

1. Twitter Bootsrap : Which will give the responsiveness to website and you can use media queries to chnage display for the different resolutions.Bootstrap grid flow to display the HTML
2. HTML 5 features which can easily embedded with bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

There are different front-end frameworks that could help you with responsiveness (partial list):

- [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/);
- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/);
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/);
- [UIkit](http://getuikit.com/);
- [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/);
- [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/).

For a comparison, check [this](http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html).